# How to Iterate through nested objects within a Json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops, nested-loops

I am working with a JSON file where I want to get the keys for each value. Below is a snip-it of the file I am working with.

```json
{"id":"2769","data":{"accommodation":{"town":"Dublin","addressYears":1,"postcode":"K12 Y453","accommodationType":"select"},"bankDetails":{"payee":"Name","Number":"1234567890"},"creditReport":{"creditReportMessageId":"message id","creditReportContractCode":"contact code","creditReportSource":"cccs"},"dependents":{"dependentsCount":0,"dependentsCount2":0}}}
```

I have tried to build three loops to get the keys that are nested twice.

```
for i in data:
    print(i)
    for j in data[i]:
        print(j)
        for k in data(j):
            print(k)
```

However, I get the following error.

```
'dict' object is not callable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for i in data:
    print(i)
    if type(i) is dict:
        for j in i:
            print(j)
            if type(j) is dict:
                for k in j:
                print(k)
```

You need to use square brackets to reference an element in a dictionary

Comment: Hi @matiwg, that was a bad error on my behalf however, this causes a key error as 'id' does not have a nested list.

Comment: FYI:
KeyError: '2'

Comment: @JordanWilkes hope this edit helps

Comment: this edit returns the top keys, not the nested keys i.e., id and data. I tried to add another loop but no joy. Is there a way to check if a key contains a nested list and to loop through it if it does?

Comment: @Jordan121 The answer by @martiwg already shows how to check for nested dicts, it just has an error in the conditions. It should check for `type(data[i]) is dict` instead of just `type(i)`. And after that for `type(data[i][j]) is dict`. Also the last loop should loop over `data[i][j]`.